# gradlew assembleRelease generate two versions of APK (the new and old one)

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I generate the APK file via `gradlew assembleRelease` and I run this APK via `adb install app-release.apk` . The problem is that whene I run the app the first time everything is okey but if I close the app ( android task button > close all ) and rerun the app I get the very old version of my app (generated two months ago).

**What I've tried:**

```
cd android && ./graldew clean // before generating the APK
```

I follow this steps too:

```
1.Delete (index.android.bundle) files inside directory android/app/src/main/assets.

2.run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

3.Delete folders (drawable,drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi,raw) inside android/app/src/main/res

4. ./gradlew clean > ./gradlew assembleReleae
```

But it doen't work. this is more informations:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "ktIP",
  //...
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {

    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.1",


  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.38",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.13",
    //...
  },
}

//build.gradlew
buildscript {
    ext      { 
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 30 
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I can edit my question for more informations.

The same probleme if I run `react-native run-android --variant=release` but i works good with debug version, `react-native run-android`

I don't know if it's because of the old version of React Native(59).Do I have to upgrade to 63

Comment: maybe try to clean the build folder which contains apk before generating a new one. use rm -rf app/build

Comment: I think running `./gradlew clean` remove already this folder

Comment: but how the first run it run the last one

Comment: sorry, didn't understand the question

Comment: the first time I run the app directly after the installation it runs correctly with the last changes but if I close the app via the task button (android) and re-run the app I get the older version of my app with the same apk already installed.